# How to get all the expression with pattern match?

Tags: pattern-matching

The `FullForm` of my equation `final`(obtained from `System Modeler`) is:

```
equations = FullForm@final
```

After copy the plain output, 
which output:

```
plainEqns=And[Equal[
  Times[2.`, QuantityVariable["fixed1.s0", "Length"], 
   QuantityVariable["spring1.c", "SpringConstant"]], 
  Plus[Times[-2.`, QuantityVariable["sine1.offset", "Unitless"]], 
   Times[QuantityVariable["mass1.L", "Length"], 
    QuantityVariable["spring1.c", "SpringConstant"]], 
   Times[2.`, QuantityVariable["spring1.c", "SpringConstant"], 
    QuantityVariable["spring1.s_rel0", "Length"]], 
   Times[-2.`, QuantityVariable["sine1.amplitude", "Unitless"], 
    Sin[Plus[QuantityVariable["sine1.phase", "Angle"], 
      Times[6.283185307179586`, 
       QuantityVariable["sine1.freqHz", "Frequency"], 
       Plus[t, Times[-1.`, 
         QuantityVariable["sine1.startTime", "Time"]]]]]]], 
   Times[2.`, QuantityVariable["spring1.c", "SpringConstant"], 
    QuantityVariable["mass1.s", "Length"][t]], 
   Times[2.`, QuantityVariable["mass1.m", "Mass"], 
    Derivative[1][QuantityVariable["mass1.v", "Speed"]][t]]]], 
 Equal[Times[QuantityVariable["spring2.c", "SpringConstant"], 
   QuantityVariable["damper1.s_rel", "Length"][t]], 
  Plus[Times[-1.`, QuantityVariable["sine2.offset", "Unitless"]], 
   Times[QuantityVariable["spring2.c", "SpringConstant"], 
    QuantityVariable["spring2.s_rel0", "Length"]], 
   Times[-1.`, QuantityVariable["sine2.amplitude", "Unitless"], 
    Sin[Plus[QuantityVariable["sine2.phase", "Angle"], 
      Times[6.283185307179586`, 
       QuantityVariable["sine2.freqHz", "Frequency"], 
       Plus[t, Times[-1.`, 
         QuantityVariable["sine2.startTime", "Time"]]]]]]], 
   Times[-1.`, 
    QuantityVariable["damper1.d", "TranslationalDampingConstant"], 
    QuantityVariable["damper1.v_rel", "Speed"][t]], 
   Times[-1.`, QuantityVariable["mass2.m", "Mass"], 
    Derivative[1][QuantityVariable["damper1.v_rel", "Speed"]][t]]]], 
 Equal[QuantityVariable["mass1.v", "Speed"][t], 
  Derivative[1][QuantityVariable["mass1.s", "Length"]][t]], 
 Equal[Derivative[1][QuantityVariable["damper1.s_rel", "Length"]][t], 
  QuantityVariable["damper1.v_rel", "Speed"][t]]]
```

How could I get all the expressions with a pattern `QuantityVariable[var, SI]`? Such as `QuantityVariable["mass1.L", "Length"]`.

**Note**

I have finished it, using:
    Cases[List @@ planFinal, _QuantityVariable, -1]

Thanks for your attention, thank you, @bills
**Background**

I wish I can solve the simplified differential equations with `DSolve`.

Comment: Maybe you could find a simple example where the same problem occurs?

Comment: @bills I have edited the original question. Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
expr = ToExpression@TagBox[...]

Cases[FullForm[expr], QuantityVariable[x : _, y : _] :> {x, y}, Infinity]
```

Comment: Why `QuantityVariable[x : _, y : _]` and not just `QuantityVariable[x_, y_]`?

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive Indeed.